# How can I configure nginx to be able to upload a 100GB file?

Tags: nginx

In my nginx file I know that I can set the `client_max_body_size 20000M;` but I was wondering if anyone knew what the maximum file upload limit is?

For example if I set it to `100000M` would I then actually be able to upload a 100GB file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nadermx:

You can disable it.

This is nginx manual explanation:

> "Setting size to 0 disables checking of client request body size."

And there will be no limitation.

You can read more in: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Comment: Be aware that if your `nginx` faces the public Internet this is probably a really bad idea to keep in place for long without other measures to check for abuse.  Also make sure temp dirs used by `nginx` have enough space.